# How does the VLOOKUP and VALUE syntax work in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Suppose that I have a range of data in Column A that is in text format, first I want to change the format of data to number/value.

The code I came up with is:
Method 1:

```
Sub Test123()
    Dim data As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim rowNo As Integer
    Dim answer As String
    
    rowNo = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        
    For count = 2 To rowNo
        data = Range("A" & count).Value

        Range("B" & count).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(data),Table1,2,FALSE)"

    Next count
```

Method 2:

```
        answer = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(data2, Sheet1!Table1, 2, False)
        Range("B" & count).Value = answer
```

The correct answer given by my tutor is

```
Range("B" & count).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(VALUE(A" & count & "),Table1,2,FALSE)"
```

Question 1: Why do my methods not working?

Question 2: I can't seem to figure out the underlying syntax `VALUE(A" & count & ")` here. Could anyone please help me to understand? Also, is there a repository where I can read more about these syntax?

Comment: It does not work because `data` is a simple string in the way you try it... It should be something like `"=VLOOKUP(VALUE(" & data & "),Table1,2,FALSE)"`, to consider `data` a variable... But `VLookup` can be used to directly return an array and place it in the necessary place.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the  next way. The way of `VLookup` using will generate an array which will be dropped in the necessary range:

```
Sub Test123()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rowNo As Long, rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim rngTbl As Range, tbl As ListObject
  
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = sh.ListObjects("Table25") 'my tested table...
                                        'Please, use here your real one name!
    Set rngTbl = tbl.DataBodyRange
    rowNo = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     Set rngA = sh.Range("A2:A" & rowNo)
     Set rngB = sh.Range("B2:B" & rowNo)
     rngB.value = Application.VLookup(rngA, rngTbl, 2, False)
     'If liking a more fancy way, to return what you want in case of 
     ' no match (instead of `#N/A`), please uncomment the next line:
     'rngB.value = Application.IfNa(Application.VLookup(rngA, rngTbl, 2, False), "Ups...")
End Sub
```

The above code should be considered as an improved version...

As mentioned in my comment, data is a simple string in the way you try it. It should be used in the next way: `"=VLOOKUP(VALUE(" & data & "),Table1,2,FALSE)"`, to make the code considering `data` a variable...

Comment: @JeffCh Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it behave as you need?